# UserAccountManager superuser not loggin in

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to add to my UserAccountManager, a way of creating a superuser so that I can easily manage my database, my problem is that when I create the super user from the terminal, everything seems ok, I don't get errors, but when I try to log in the default django admin page, it says that no staff account with those credentials is found. I have tried deleting my database, removing and redoing migrations.

This is my models.py

```
class UserAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('User must have an email')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        return self.create_user(email, password, first_name, last_name, **extra_fields)



class UserAccount(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']
```